# jQuery draggable clone is not working

Tags: jquery

jQuery Draggable clone not working. I tried searching. but I couldn't find the solution.

HTML

```
<div id="start">
</div>
```

Script

```
$("#start").draggable({
    helper: 'clone'
});
```

Style

```
#start {
    margin:10px;
    height:60px;
    width:100px;
    border:solid 2px #FD9395;
    border-radius:50%;
    background-color:#DBFC99;
    z-index:100;
}
```

Without `{helper:'clone'}`, the code is working perfect. After adding the helper attribute, div is not draggable.

Answer (score 2):

Actually your code works just fine, it's just that the cloned element has no styling so you never see it (it's not an exact clone and doesn't clone the ID of your original element).

The cloned element gets a few classes automatically (`ui-draggable-dragging` and `ui-draggable`) so you can style them and see it work. E.g.

```
.ui-draggable {
  margin: 10px;
  height: 60px;
  width: 100px;
  border: solid 2px #FD9395;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #DBFC99;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/ru7190q7/)**

Comment: Thank you so much for you answer. It works fine. But what if i have more than one div's? Each div is having different styles. If i add style to common .ui-draggable class, after dragging all div's is getting same style.

Comment: You'd need some JavaScript then to get information about the element you dragged to identify it and apply styling to the clone based on that.